# how to roll a multilabel dataframe into single column in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation, multilabel-classification

I have the following dataframe `originalData`

```
   ID    Y1    Y2    Y3 X1     X2     X3
1 111  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 12 junior  45.55
2 112 FALSE FALSE  TRUE 15 junior 458.54
3 113  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 16 senior  48.79
```

I would like to get the following result

```
   ID YCOMBIN X1     X2     X3
1 111      Y1 12 junior  45.55
2 111      Y2 12 junior  45.55
3 112      Y3 15 junior 458.54
4 113      Y1 16 senior  48.79
5 113      Y2 16 senior  48.79
```

I belive the my example is more clear than a long explanation. In case it is not. I would like to roll all my outcome (in my case Y1 and Y2) into a single YCOMBIN column only if the value of the adhoc outcome is TRUE. Doing so I may obviously repeat the ID and all predictors (X1 and X2) if an ID has more than 1 TRUE value on the outcome.

What is the best way to achive the desired result?

Data source:

```
originalData <- structure(list(ID = 111:113, Y1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), Y2 = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE), Y3 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), X1 = c(12L, 15L, 16L
), X2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("junior", "senior"
), class = "factor"), X3 = c(45.55, 458.54, 48.79)), .Names = c("ID", 
"Y1", "Y2", "Y3", "X1", "X2", "X3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options.

Using dplyr and tidyr

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
originalData %>%
  gather(key = "YCOMBIN", value = "value", Y1, Y2, Y3) %>%
  filter(value) %>%
  select(-value)
```

Using only dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
originalData %>%
  mutate(
    YCOMBIN = ifelse(Y1, "Y1", ifelse(Y2, "Y2", "Y3"))
  ) %>%
  select(-matches("Y[[:digit:]]"))
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, i like the first solution. But in real life my Y are large and have different names. Is there possible to use something like  gather(key = "YCOMBIN", value = "value", originalData[,2:4]). I tried but it does not work.

Comment: In that case, you can use `gather_`. `gather_(key = "YCOMBIN", value = "value", names(originalData[,2:4])`.

Comment: or `gather(key = "YCOMBIN", value = "value", starts_with("Y")`. See `?dplyr::select()` for the options like starts_with(), ends_with(), matches(), ...